# Hibernate Criteria multiple rowCounts from a single query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm wondering if there is a way to create a single criteria query and return multiple counts based on unique restrictions.

Example

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EmployeeProfile.class);

    Integer pAccrualBalance = ((Number)criteria
            .add(Restrictions.gt("pAccrualBalance", BigDecimal.ZERO))
            .setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();

    Integer employeeCount = ((Number)criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult()).intValue();

    logger.info("verify pAccrualBalance import count " + pAccrualBalance);

    logger.info("verify employee import count " + employeeCount);
```

The problem with this code is the pAccrualBalance restriction restricts the employeeCount result set. I'd like to get the unrestricted count for employeeCount without having to do a separate query.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to join to the table twice... Whilst this can be done with Criteria, it's often easier in HQL.

```
select count(ep1.id), count(ep2.id)
from EmployeeProfile as ep1
join EmployeeProfile as ep2
where ep2.pAccrualBalance > 0
```